How to fetch the users list from user manager in sitecore xm cloud and expose it through layout service
We have one functionality to fetch the list of users from user manager in Sitecore xm cloud and pass the data to layout service. It's a headless approach and we are only using next js and not using .net.
How to achieve this?
We want the list of usernames of the Sitecore users to be exposed to front end for some functionality.

Welcome to Sitecore Stack Exchange! Please could you expand a little bit more on your requirements - how do you want to use the list of users in the Next.js application? I'm asking because XM Cloud users should be used only for accessing the CMS and not the front-end application https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/33627/how-should-security-be-handled-for-xm-cloud-headless-with-experience-edge. So if we better understand your requirements, we can recommend some solutions.

This is easy, you can't do this in XM Cloud. Why do you need a list of content authors?

True that, Can't see or recall a direct option to take the list out for content authors.
